# How to undo serialize list on Django

Tags: python, json, django, serialization, deserialization

I serialized a list of Django models like this:

```
serialize_list = serializers.serialize("json", my_list)
```

and now I want to deserialize it and get back a list of Django models.
Instead, when I do 
`deserialize_list = serializers.deserialize("json", serialize_list )`

I get a list of DeserializedObject models and not the original list.

My question is: how can I get the original list back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each element of the deserialized list has an `object` attribute, which contains the model instance.

```
original = [item.object for item in deserialize_list]
```

Comment: Thank you! exactly what I needed